# Sending an email to outlook with emoji characters using C#

Tags: c#, emoji, smtpclient

I have a user input on a web page.
They are able to type a message and send.

The message gets sent to them via SMTP and the client they'll be using is outlook.

The problem I am getting is that emoji [‍‍♂️] are coming through as varying amount of ?? question marks.

There's also a number of problematic characters that come through when they paste content from work like special quotes and the em dash which is often substituted in word when people type a dash.

I know outlook supports emoji as I can type them in with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> and send them fine. But this is getting mangled somehow when I send it through the SMTP client.

Debugging is showing the emoji correctly before sending it through the SMTP client.

Any ideas what I need to do to get it to send without resorting to stripping these characters out? I'd like for people to be able to use these emoji if they like.

Comment: It sounds like an encoding issue. What encoding are you setting the email to?

Comment: The email needs to be either html or Rich Text (not text).  Html you have to add to SMTP as an html attachment.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too. I have already set the MailMessage `IsBodyHtml` to `true`. Maybe I need to do more than that. I'll do some digging.

Comment: That was it, should have known. `message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` @Steve if you want to create an answer I'll mark it as such, if not then I'll just add it and take the credit 

Comment: Just you take credit :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve for making me reconsider the obvious

Turns out all I needed to do was set the `BodyEncoding` to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` on the message.
Setting the `IsBodyHtml` property to `true` was not enough.

Not sure what the default is for this to not work without setting it to UTF8 but oh well.

`mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding